# Received UDP message has incorrect length

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am recieving a UDP message from a DatagramSocket and am trying to parse the message like this:

```
this.broadSock.receive(recvPacket);

// Decode response
byte[] response = recvPacket.getData();
String strResp = new String(response);
String[] splitResp = strResp.split("\\s+");
log.debug("The String: " + strResp + " has the length " + strResp.length());

InetAddress lobbyAdress = InetAddress.getByName(splitResp[0].substring(1));
String portStr = splitResp[1];
int lobbyPort = Integer.parseInt(portStr);
```

I am getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080"
```

So there is something wrong with the received String as the debug output gives me:

```
The String: /192.168.0.11 8080 has the length 256
```

Anybody an idea why this is happening?

Comment: which line are you getting this exception. the last line seems to be fine.

Comment: Getting it from the last line

Comment: this is strange... you can iterate through the chars in string and print their hex values.. may be the string has some unprintable chars that do not match `\s`

Comment: are you sending the udp message as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length is provided, and you're ignoring it. It should be:

```
String strResp = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
String[] splitResp = strResp.split("\\s+");
log.debug("The response: " + strResp + " has the length " + packet.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `strResp.length` is 256 is a symptom of a bug in your code. It should be 18 instead.

You are constructing `strResp` using the *entire length* of the `DatagramPacket` buffer without regard to how many bytes are actually in that buffer. `DatagramPacket.getData()` does not return a new `byte[]` for just the bytes received. It returns the entire buffer.

That means `strResp` ends up with 238 extra characters after the port number, and they are not whitespace characters that would be stripped off by `split("\\s+")`, so `splitResp[1]`, and thus `strPort`, ends up with more than just digit characters in it, thus violating the requirements of `Integer.parseInt()`.

You need to take the `DatagramPacket` length into account when constructing `strResp`:

```
byte[] response = recvPacket.getData();
int responseOffset = recvPacket.getOffset();
int responseLength = recvPacket.getLength();
String strResp = new String(response, responseOffset, responseLength);
```