# Strange behaviour with Datagram in UDP receive function in Android

Tags: java, android, udp, datagram

I'm trying to implement an UDP test to learn about it. I've a server application in c# for windows and a client app for Android.

I'm trying to implement a homemade discovery service. Server is continuosly listening for UDP packages with a fixed string ("LazyRemote"). When it receives that string it sends another string to the client ("LazyRemote_192.168.1.17:2016")
I've checked with wireshark that the data sent in both directions is correct but I'm receiving something incorrect in the client application.

The code for android is this:

```
buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            progress.show();
            //This code is executed when user clicks connect button. As it could be a long running operation, it's executed in a new thread to avoid blocking UI
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String ipAddress = "";
                    SocketClass my_socketClass = new SocketClass();
                    InetAddress UDPaddress = my_socketClass.getBroadcastAddress();
                    int UDPport = 15000;

                    if(initializationDone == false){
                        initializationDone = true;

                        try {
                            socket_send = new DatagramSocket();
                            socket_send.setBroadcast(true);
                            socket_send.setSoTimeout(6000);
                            socket_receive = new DatagramSocket(UDPport, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    try {

                        byte[] send_buff = "LazyRemote".getBytes();
                        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(send_buff, send_buff.length,UDPaddress,UDPport);
                        socket_send.send(sendPacket);

                    }catch (Exception ex){

                        showToast("Imposible enviar primer ack");
                    }


                    byte[] receive_buff = new byte[30];
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receive_buff, receive_buff.length);

                    try {

                        socket_receive.receive(receivePacket);
                        String receivedData = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8");
                        if (receivedData.contains("LazyRemote")) {


                            SocketClass my_socket = new SocketClass(receivePacket.getAddress().toString().substring(1), 2016);
                            SocketClass.ConnectionStatus connectionStatus = my_socket.establishConnection();

                            //Remove progressdialog after establishConnection finishes.
                            progress.dismiss();

                            //Check connection status.
                            if (connectionStatus.status == true) {

                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                socket_receive.close();
                                socket_send.close();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActionPerformer.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        showToast("No se han encontrado servidores");
                    }
                    //mLock.release();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that receive function is working but it is receiving wrong data. (It is receiving the same string that the client sends to the server to initialize descovery ("LazyRemote")).

It must be a stupid mistake but i can't solve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Received UDP message has incorrect length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533359/received-udp-message-has-incorrect-length)

Comment: The issue is not the lenght. I receive something that's not being sent. I think is something related with the buffers but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your UDP sent packet can also be received by your client socket if you are listening on the same port that you are sending on.  You just need to filter that data out of your data analysis code.  You should be able to see that the source address is the same as the client IP address.